# Is It Possible To Skip Gradle Tasks Using Environment Variables?

Tags: gradle

I am working with a third-party that runs gradle as part of a bigger process which leaves me with limited options on how to interact with gradle.

I want to skip some task but I don't have the ability to pass extra parameters to gradle. e.g. `--exclude-task annoyingTask`

I can pass JVM args, set environment variables and use the `init.gradle` in the home directory.

Can I use any of these to force the build to skip a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the Gradle build script itself judging by the restrictions you have, [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)
 is the only option you have.

If you know the name of the tasks, you can do something like the following (pseudo):

`init.gradle`

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    def annoyingTask = allTasks.filter { name == "someAnnoyingTask" }
    annoyingTask.configure {
        onlyIf {
            System.getenv("skip") == true
        }
    }
}
```

Refs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:using_a_predicate